# Java-8 JSONArray to HashMap

Tags: java, json, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I'm trying to convert `JSONArray` to a `Map<String,String>` via `streams` and `Lambdas`. The following isn't working:

```
org.json.simple.JSONArray jsonArray = new org.json.simple.JSONArray();
jsonArray.add("pankaj");
HashMap<String, String> stringMap = jsonArray.stream().collect(HashMap<String, String>::new, (map,membermsisdn) -> map.put((String)membermsisdn,"Error"), HashMap<String, String>::putAll);
HashMap<String, String> stringMap1 = jsonArray.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(member -> member, member -> "Error"));
```

To Avoid typecasting in `Line 4`, I'm doing `Line 3`

`Line 3` gives the following errors:

```
Multiple markers at this line
- The type HashMap<String,String> does not define putAll(Object, Object) that is applicable here
- The method put(String, String) is undefined for the type Object
- The method collect(Supplier, BiConsumer, BiConsumer) in the type Stream is not applicable for the arguments (HashMap<String, String>::new, (<no type> map, <no type> membermsisdn) 
 -> {}, HashMap<String, String>::putAll)
```

And `Line 4` gives the following error:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to HashMap<String,String>
```

I'm trying to learn Lambdas and streams. Can somebody help me out?

Comment: I don't think this is necessarily a duplicate. This is converting a JSONArray, and the problem arises from the use of lambdas

Comment: @ozOli READ/THINK twice before you downvote or reacting on something you think is wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would appear that json-simple's `JSONArray` extends an `ArrayList` without providing any generic types. This causes `stream` to return a `Stream` that doesn't have a type either.

Knowing this, we can program on the interface of `List` instead of `JSONArray`

```
List<Object> jsonarray = new JSONArray();
```

Doing this will allow us to stream properly like so:

```
Map<String, String> map = jsonarray.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s, s -> "value"));
```

Comment: That assignment generates a compiler warning.  It should be `List<?>`, not `List<Object>`.

Comment: @VGR It doesn't generate any warning. I just tried.

Comment: It generates a warning depending on your settings. However, it would also generate a warning on `.add` so I didn't think too much of it.

Comment: @SamSun Does adding a `.map(Object::toString)` would call toString of Object class or JSONArray class? I guess JSONArray's, right?

Comment: It calls `toString` on each element of the `JSONArray`

Comment: Yes, that's right. But, which class's implementation would be executed? Because `JSONArray` also has it's own implementation of `toString` & `Object` also and both are different

Comment: `JSONArray`'s `toString` will be called